# How to do calculations ONLY on the 2 last bars?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I wrote a script that I should use `barstate.islast` because of the heavy calculations. But the problem is that I sometimes need also the previous candle too to check if the condition was met there or not. So what should I do? Can say like if ( `barstate.islast` or `barstate.islast[1]`).

I tried but I'm not sure if `barstate.islast[1]` is working or not (because backtesting it in my strategy is so hard and weird and I'm getting confused)

Comment: What techniques are you using for debugging the script?

Comment: Also, it would be great if you share as much code as you can. For the most part, anyone trying to help you with it won't care about the content. It's not like something secretive for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history reference operator `[]` on your condition.

So, something like this.

```
cond = ...

if barstate.islast
    another_cond = cond1 and cond[1]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but that doesnt work in my case. as i said the script is heavy and i should put a  "if barstate.islast " at the first line of the script so i dont get "calculation error"  . as a result the script only run on last candle and doesnt have access to previous candle informations and cond[1] doesnt work. i need a way to do the calculations on the previous bar too